# How can I work around this JRE bug in getNetworkPrefixLength()?

Tags: java

There appears to be a known bug in the JRE implementation:

- http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6707289
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7107883

But how can I fix it without updating the JRE/JDK? I need to get broadcast address, and use  `getBroadcast()` for this, but it returns 0.0.0.0 (because `getNetworkPrefixLength()` returns -1, although the real network mask is 24).